# Devise gem User Authentication Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This is my code for my index.html.erb scaffold
 as you can see the if else stops a user to  "show, edit or destroy" the
entries. However, they can create a new Rota entry by clicking New
Rotum. I can get rid of the admin part in Show, edit, destroy and
everyone will be able to do everything. But I want a user to be able to
only show edit destroy their OWN entry and not everyone elses too
because that is what happens when I authenticate a user to do this?

```
 <h1>Listing rota</h1>

 <table id = "tabletest">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Mobile</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Category</th>
  <th>Other</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
   </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
   <% @rota.each do |rotum| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= rotum.name %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.mobile %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.email %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.category %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.other %></td>

 <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', rotum %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_rotum_path(rotum) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', rotum, method: :delete, data: {
   confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
   <% end %>
         <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>

<br>
   <% if user_session %>
<%= link_to 'New Rotum', new_rotum_path %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relationship between `user` and `rota` is a `has_many`, your index controller should be:

```
class RotasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rota = current_user.rotas
  end
end
```

`current_user` is a helper method defined by Devise as shown [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:**
If you want to show the rotas that a user has created in the table.

```
class RotasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rota = Rota.where(current_user.try(:admin?) ? true : {user_id: current_user.id})
  end
end
```

Here it will fetch all the records for admin and if the user is not admin, it will fetch the related records.

And in the view file

```
<tbody>
   <% @rota.each do |rotum| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= rotum.name %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.mobile %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.email %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.category %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.other %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', rotum %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_rotum_path(rotum) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', rotum, method: :delete, data: {
   confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

**Case 2:**
In another case, if you want to show all the records to every user but the user can access the 'show, edit, delete', only if he has created that.. Then you need to do something else.

```
class RotasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rota = Rota.all
    @is_admin = current_user.try(:admin?)
  end
end
```

And in the view

```
<tbody>
   <% @rota.each do |rotum| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= rotum.name %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.mobile %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.email %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.category %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.other %></td>
    <% if @is_admin || (rotum.user_id == current_user.id)
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', rotum %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_rotum_path(rotum) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', rotum, method: :delete, data: {
   confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td colspan='3'> &nbsp; </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Hope, it will work for you. :)

Comment: I tried this and the admin can do everything but when a user signs in. it says, "
NoMethodError at /rota

undefined method `user_id' for #<Rotum:0x00000005175cc8>
"